# Jquery animate scrollTop causes the click event to stop working on IOS safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile-safari

The codes below have links which when clicked will animate the body's scrollTop to 400 or 600. It is working fine on desktops but not on iOS safari. The scrolling animation is working, but the animation is somehow disabled the click event listener. The user have to do some actions (like scrolling the page manually) to re-enable the clicking event.

To simulate the problem, click on the first link, the page will then scroll down. After that, click the other link, this time (on iOS safari), the link clicking doesn't work anymore. Try scrolling down a little bit, and the links will work again.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
#test, #test2 {
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    top: 200;
}
#test2 {
    top: 250;
}

#job{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 200px;
}
</style>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#test").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('body').animate({scrollTop: 400});
        });

        $("#test2").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('body').animate({scrollTop: 600});
        });
    });
</script>


<a href="#job" id="test"> Test one</a>
<a href="#job" id="test2"> Test two</a>

<div id="job">
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"

"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"

</div>
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying `html` as well, this is what you generally see for animated scrolling as a fix to work across browsers:

```
$('html, body').animate.....
```